# JavaFX modify polygons

Tags: javafx, polygon, shapes

Is there a way to modify a polygon in JavaFX? For example if I have a triangle and I press and then drag a point from that triangle, the triangle will modify with the new coordinates of the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Layer some control nodes over the corners of the polygon.
2. Attach appropriate event handlers to the control nodes so that they can be dragged around.
3. Modify the polygon's points as the control node is moved (using change listeners attached to each of the control node's location properties).

Here is a sample solution:

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** Drag the anchors around to change a polygon's points. */
public class TriangleManipulator extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }

  // main application layout logic.
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Polygon triangle = createStartingTriangle();

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(triangle);
    root.getChildren().addAll(createControlAnchorsFor(triangle.getPoints()));

    stage.setTitle("Triangle Manipulation Sample");
    stage.setScene(
        new Scene(
            root,
            400, 400, Color.ALICEBLUE
        )
    );
    stage.show();
  }

  // creates a triangle.
  private Polygon createStartingTriangle() {
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon();

    triangle.getPoints().setAll(
        100d, 100d,
        150d, 50d,
        250d, 150d
    );

    triangle.setStroke(Color.FORESTGREEN);
    triangle.setStrokeWidth(4);
    triangle.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
    triangle.setFill(Color.CORNSILK.deriveColor(0, 1.2, 1, 0.6));

    return triangle;
  }

  // @return a list of anchors which can be dragged around to modify points in the format [x1, y1, x2, y2...]
  private ObservableList<Anchor> createControlAnchorsFor(final ObservableList<Double> points) {
    ObservableList<Anchor> anchors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i+=2) {
      final int idx = i;

      DoubleProperty xProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(points.get(i));
      DoubleProperty yProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(points.get(i + 1));

      xProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldX, Number x) {
          points.set(idx, (double) x);
        }
      });

      yProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldY, Number y) {
          points.set(idx + 1, (double) y);
        }
      });

      anchors.add(new Anchor(Color.GOLD, xProperty, yProperty));
    }

    return anchors;
  }

  // a draggable anchor displayed around a point.
  class Anchor extends Circle {
    private final DoubleProperty x, y;

    Anchor(Color color, DoubleProperty x, DoubleProperty y) {
      super(x.get(), y.get(), 10);
      setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
      setStroke(color);
      setStrokeWidth(2);
      setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);

      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;

      x.bind(centerXProperty());
      y.bind(centerYProperty());
      enableDrag();
    }

    // make a node movable by dragging it around with the mouse.
    private void enableDrag() {
      final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
      setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
          dragDelta.x = getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
          dragDelta.y = getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();
          getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        }
      });
      setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        }
      });
      setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
          if (newX > 0 && newX < getScene().getWidth()) {
            setCenterX(newX);
          }
          double newY = mouseEvent.getY() + dragDelta.y;
          if (newY > 0 && newY < getScene().getHeight()) {
            setCenterY(newY);
          }
        }
      });
      setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
          }
        }
      });
      setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    // records relative x and y co-ordinates.
    private class Delta { double x, y; }
  }
}
```

[image: triangular]

I derived this solution from: [CubicCurve JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056795/cubiccurve-javafx)