# How to draw a line with multiple points in javaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a class that extends Line or Path or something(not sure)

The class is used to create a line between two points, The Source and the Target.

When the user clicks on the line, a point should be added. This point (Nail) can then be dragged around and the line moves accordingly.

Currently the Source and Target are objects of a class that extends Circle and Nail is a separate class that extends circle.

These objects are added to the pane and drawn.

eg. Points A and B : A->B
After adding Nail: A->N->B

The Line class should hold an arraylist of nail objects. I just need to know what the Line class should extend. I am not sure as it needs to update itself.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [`Polyline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polyline.html) class?

Comment: Just saw it and i think it is exactly what i need. Thank you!!

Comment: With regards to the drag and drop portion, you could combine the Polyline suggestion with the solution used in [JavaFX modify polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981274/javafx-modify-polygons) using the [source code here](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5375786) to manage the draggable anchor points.

Comment: I am having another issue with the start and end points. I was originally using extend Line and could use setEndX() and setStartX() but now i cannot. Any suggestions

Comment: Okay figures it out. Replaced it with getAllPoints().set(0, val) and so on

Comment: Glad that did help. Feel free to answer/solve your own question to help other users, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe behaviour can be achieved using PolyLine. To reference different points on the line use getAllPoints().set/add/..