# How to create bindings to the points of a Polygon?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an isosceles triangle that functions as an arrow tip, so I would bind its points relative to the endpoint of the `Line` it's on.

But `Polygon` seems to only accept an array of doubles in its constructor, and so I'm unsure of how to do the binding with each individual point of the triangle. I know that `getPoints` returns an `ObservableList` but I'm unsure of how to use the listener on it to update the points of the triangle based on the movement or rotation of the `Line` it's attached to, since to my understanding, I would first have to actually have the points of the triangle change, which is my problem to begin with.

Edit:

The only solution I could think of is a very verbose one: creating a change listener on each `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, `endY` property of the line, and altering each of the three coordinate pairs, or six total points, within `getPoints`. Perhaps someone has a more elegant solution.

Comment: Simlar: [JavaFX modify polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981274/javafx-modify-polygons)

Comment: The solution you describe doesn't sound that verbose, tbh; you probably have to recompute the coordinates of the polygon anyway, and you can encapsulate that in a method. Then you can do something like `List.of(line.startXProperty(), line.startYProperty(), line.endXProperty(), line.endYProperty()).forEach(p -> p.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> recomputeArrow()));` Perhaps you only need to add a listener to `line.boundsInLocalProperty()`?

Comment: I see. I was thinking there would be some piece of information that I was missing, because so far a lot of the stuff I had trouble with had more elegant solutions than my extremely verbose methods, and they required a lot of digging to find. Thanks for the confirmation, I'll get on it.

Comment: Or: `Bindings.bindContent(arrow.getPoints(), new ListBinding<Double>() { bind(line.startXProperty(), line.endXProperty(), ...); } @Override protected ObservableList<Double> computeValue() { /* compute points here */});`