# How to move arrow at the edge of circle specially for quadcurve

Tags: javafx

i'm trying to make connect circle and quadcurve with arrow with these tutorials:
[JavaFX line/curve with arrow head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702519/javafx-line-curve-with-arrow-head),
[CubicCurve JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056795/cubiccurve-javafx),
[JavaFX: How to connect two Nodes by a Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748744/javafx-how-to-connect-two-nodes-by-a-line)

My problem: Arrow is not connected with quadcurve and not at the edge of cirle when i move quadcurve
[image: Arrow is not connected with quadcurve and not at the edge of cirle when i move quadcurve]

this is my project repos : https://github.com/ehnsnk/cho_ford_min_max

i work in develop branch, these are the shortcut of my application

CTRL+Right Click : Delete Circle,
Right Click : Delete QuadCurve 
CTRL+Left Click : to link two Circle,

The shape class is in the edu.emit.project.view.shape package

And V(xi,xj) must follow controlX,controlY 

The data is exo1.ro at https://github.com/ehnsnk/unnamed-proj/,
Thanks

```
        /*
         * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
         * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
        package edu.emit.project.view.shape;

        import edu.emit.project.Main;
        import edu.emit.project.controller.FordFulkersonFXController;
        import edu.emit.project.model.serializable.SommetSerializable;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;
        import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
        import javafx.event.EventHandler;
        import javafx.scene.Cursor;
        import javafx.scene.Group;
        import javafx.scene.control.Label;
        import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
        import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
        import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
        import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
        import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;

        /**
         *
         * @author heniroger
         */
        public class SommetFX extends Circle{
            Main app;
            private int id=0;
            private final SommetFX context = this;
            private FordFulkersonFXController controller;

            private Label lblName;
            private TextField txfLambda;                        
            private Label lblLambda;
            private double lambda;
            private boolean deletable = false;

            public static int SOMMET_TYPE_X1 =0;
            public static int SOMMET_TYPE_XI =1;
            public static int SOMMET_TYPE_XN =2;
            private int typeSommet = SOMMET_TYPE_XI;


            private ArrayList  listLiens = new ArrayList();

            private SommetSerializable sommetSerializable;


            public SommetFX() {
                super();
                setFill(Color.WHITE);
                setStroke(Color.BLACK.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
                setStrokeWidth(2);
                setStrokeType(StrokeType.CENTERED);
                setCenterX(150);
                setCenterY(150);
                setRadius(30.0f);

                lblName = new Label("X1");
                lblLambda= new Label("\u03BB=");
                txfLambda = new TextField("0");
                txfLambda.setPrefWidth(50);
                txfLambda.setEditable(false);

                initialize();
                enableDrag();
                enableMouseClickToBind();
            }

            public void setApp(Main app){this.app = app;}
            public void lier(DoubleProperty x, DoubleProperty y){
                try {
                    if (app == null) {
                     throw new AppNotDefinedException();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SommetFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

               bindSommetFXComponent();


                x.bind(centerXProperty());
                y.bind(centerYProperty());

            }
            public void bindSommetFXComponent(){
                 lblName.layoutXProperty().bind(centerXProperty());
                lblName.layoutYProperty().bind(centerYProperty());
                 lblLambda.layoutXProperty().bind(centerXProperty());
                lblLambda.layoutYProperty().bind(centerYProperty());
                txfLambda.layoutXProperty().bind(centerXProperty());
                txfLambda.layoutYProperty().bind(centerYProperty());
            }
             private void enableDrag() {
              final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
              setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
                  dragDelta.x = getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
                  dragDelta.y = getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();
                  getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                  if(mouseEvent.isControlDown() && mouseEvent.isSecondaryButtonDown()){deletable = true; }
                }
              });
              setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                    if (deletable) {
                        delete();
                    }
                }
              });
              setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
                  if (newX > 0 && newX  0 && newY () {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                    setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                  }
                }
              });
              setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
                     setStroke(Color.BLACK.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
                  }
                }
              });
            }

            public class AppNotDefinedException extends Exception{

                public AppNotDefinedException()throws Exception{

                    System.err.println("App is null or not defined");

                }

            }

            /**
             * @return the lblName
             */
            public Label getLblName() {
                return lblName;
            }

            /**
             * @param lblName the lblName to set
             */
            public void setLblName(Label lblName) {
                this.lblName = lblName;
            }

            /**
             * @return the txfLambda
             */
            public TextField getTxfLambda() {
                return txfLambda;
            }

            /**
             * @param txfLambda the txfLambda to set
             */
            public void setTxfLambda(TextField txfLambda) {
                this.txfLambda = txfLambda;
            }

            public void initialize(){
                lblName.setLayoutX(getCenterX()-10);
                lblName.setLayoutY(getCenterY()-10);
                lblLambda.setLayoutX(getCenterX()-45);
                lblLambda.setLayoutY(getCenterY()-70);
                txfLambda.setLayoutX(getCenterX()-25);
                txfLambda.setLayoutY(getCenterY()-75);
            }
            public void update(){
                initialize();
            }
           private void enableMouseClickToBind(){
               setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler() {
                   @Override
                   public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                       if (event.isControlDown()) {

                           if (Tetha.startSommet != null) {
                               if (Tetha.startSommet.equals(context)) {
                                   Tetha.startSommet = null;
                                   return;
                               }
                               Tetha.endSommet = context;

                                ArcFX lien = new ArcFX();
                                Pointe pointe = new Pointe();
                                pointe.linkTo(lien, 40.0f);
                                app.pointes.add(pointe);

                                lien.setPointe(pointe);
                                lien.lier(Tetha.startSommet.centerXProperty(), Tetha.startSommet.centerYProperty(), Tetha.endSommet.centerXProperty(), Tetha.endSommet.centerYProperty());
                                lien.setControlY(175);
                                lien.setController(getController());


                                Tetha.startSommet.getNextSommets().add(new Object[]{ Tetha.endSommet,lien});
                                Tetha.endSommet.getPreviewSommets().add(new Object[]{ Tetha.startSommet,lien});
                                Tetha.startSommet.getListNextSommets().add(Tetha.endSommet);
                                Tetha.endSommet.getListPreviewSommets().add(Tetha.startSommet);
                                Tetha.startSommet.getListLiens().add(lien);
                                Tetha.endSommet.getListLiens().add(lien);
                                lien.getListSommets().add(Tetha.startSommet);
                                lien.getListSommets().add(Tetha.endSommet);
                                lien.setV_ij(Double.parseDouble(lien.getTxfVij().getText()));
                                getController().getGraphManager().getArcFXList().add(lien);

                                Group group = (Group) context.getParent();
                                group.getChildren().addAll(pointe,lien,lien.getVij(),lien.getTxfVij());
                                pointe.update();

                                Tetha.startSommet =null;
                                Tetha.endSommet =null;

                           }else{
                               Tetha.startSommet = context;
                           }
                       }
                   }
               });
           }

            /**
             * @return the alreadyBounded
             */
            public boolean isAlreadyBounded() {
                return alreadyBounded;
            }



            /**
             * @param alreadyBounded the alreadyBounded to set
             */
            public void setAlreadyBounded(boolean alreadyBounded) {
                this.alreadyBounded = alreadyBounded;
            }

            /**
             * @return the previewSommets
             */
            public ArrayList getPreviewSommets() {
                return previewSommets;
            }

            /**
             * @param previewSommets the previewSommets to set
             */
            public void setPreviewSommets(ArrayList previewSommets) {
                this.previewSommets = previewSommets;
            }

            /**
             * @return the nextSommets
             */
            public ArrayList getNextSommets() {
                return nextSommets;
            }

            /**
             * @param nextSommets the nextSommets to set
             */
            public void setNextSommets(ArrayList nextSommets) {
                this.nextSommets = nextSommets;
            }

            /**
             * @return the listPreviewSommets
             */
            public ArrayList getListPreviewSommets() {
                return listPreviewSommets;
            }


            /**
             * @return the listLiens
             */
            public ArrayList getListLiens() {
                return listLiens;
            }

            /**
             * @param listLiens the listLiens to set
             */
            public void setListLiens(ArrayList listLiens) {
                this.listLiens = listLiens;
            }

            /**
             * @return the typeSommet
             */
            public int getTypeSommet() {
                return typeSommet;
            }

            /**
             * @param typeSommet the typeSommet to set
             */
            public void setTypeSommet(int typeSommet) {
                this.typeSommet = typeSommet;
            }

            /**
             * @return the id
             */
            public int getID() {
                return id;
            }

            /**
             * @param id the id to set
             */
            public void setID(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            /**
             * @return the lambda
             */
            public double getLambda() {
                return lambda;
            }

            /**
             * @param lambda the lambda to set
             */
            public void setLambda(double lambda) {
                this.lambda = lambda;
            }


            /**
             * @return the controller
             */
            public FordFulkersonFXController getController() {
                return controller;
            }

            /**
             * @param controller the controller to set
             */
            public void setController(FordFulkersonFXController controller) {
                this.controller = controller;
            }
            public void deleteFromGraphManager(){
                ArrayList  sommetFXList = getController().getGraphManager().getSommetFXList();
                for (int i = 0; i
```

private void enableMouseClickToBind(); method to bind  2 SommetFX(Circle)

```
        /*
         * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
         * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
        package edu.emit.project.view.shape;

        import edu.emit.project.controller.FordFulkersonFXController;
        import edu.emit.project.model.serializable.ArcSerializable;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;
        import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
        import javafx.event.EventHandler;
        import javafx.scene.Cursor;
        import javafx.scene.Group;
        import javafx.scene.control.Label;
        import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
        import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
        import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
        import javafx.scene.shape.QuadCurve;
        import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;

        /**
         *
         * @author heniroger
         */
        public class ArcFX extends QuadCurve{
            private final ArcFX context = this;
            private FordFulkersonFXController controller;

            private  Label vij = new Label("V(xi,xj)=");
            private  TextField txfVij = new TextField("0");
            private  double v_ij; 
            private Pointe pointe;

            private ArrayList listSommets = new ArrayList();
            private boolean up =true;
            private boolean deletable = false;

            private ArcSerializable arcSerializable;

            public ArcFX(){
                setStrokeWidth(2);
                setFill(Color.WHITE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0));
                setStroke(Color.BLACK.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
                setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);
              //  getStrokeDashArray().setAll(10.0,5.);
                setMouseTransparent(false);


                vij.setLayoutX(getControlX()-75);
                vij.setLayoutY(getControlY()+75);
                txfVij.setPrefWidth(50);
                txfVij.setLayoutX(getControlX()-75);
                txfVij.setLayoutY(getControlY()+75);

            } 
            public void lier(DoubleProperty startX,DoubleProperty startY,DoubleProperty endX,DoubleProperty endY){
                try {
                    if (pointe == null) {
                        throw new PointeClassNotSetException();
                    }
                } catch (PointeClassNotSetException e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ArcFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                    return;

                }
                startXProperty().bind(startX);
                startYProperty().bind(startY);
                endXProperty().bind(endX);
                endYProperty().bind(endY);
               // controlXProperty().bind(startX.add(endX));
                //controlXProperty().bind(startY.add(endY));
                getVij().layoutXProperty().bind(controlXProperty().add(75));
                getVij().layoutYProperty().bind(controlYProperty().subtract(25));
                getTxfVij().layoutXProperty().bind(controlXProperty().add(135));
                getTxfVij().layoutYProperty().bind(controlYProperty().subtract(30));

                 enableClickEvent();
                 enableDrag();
            }
            public  class  PointeClassNotSetException extends Exception{
                public PointeClassNotSetException(){
                    System.err.println("Pointe Object is not set");

                }
            }
            /**
             * @return the pointe
             */
            public Pointe getPointe() {
                return pointe;
            }

            /**
             * @param pointe the pointe to set
             */
            public void setPointe(Pointe pointe) {
                this.pointe = pointe;
            }

            private void enableClickEvent(){
                setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    }
                });
            }
            private void enableDrag(){
                  final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
                    setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler() {
                      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                        // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
                        dragDelta.x = getControlX() - mouseEvent.getX();
                        dragDelta.y = getControlY()- mouseEvent.getY();
                        getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                        if (mouseEvent.isSecondaryButtonDown()) { deletable = true; }



                      }
                    });
              setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                    if (deletable) {
                           delete();
                    }
                }
              });
              setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    if (mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                            double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
                            if (newX > 0 && newX  0 && newY () {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                   setStroke(Color.GREEN);

                  }
                }
              });
              setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler() {
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
                    setStroke(Color.BLACK.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));

                  }
                }
              });
            }

            /**
             * @return the up
             */
            public boolean isUp() {
                return up;
            }

            /**
             * @param up the up to set
             */
            public void setUp(boolean up) {
                this.up = up;
            }

            /**
             * @return the listSommets
             */
            public ArrayList getListSommets() {
                return listSommets;
            }

            /**
             * @param listSommets the listSommets to set
             */
            public void setListSommets(ArrayList listSommets) {
                this.listSommets = listSommets;
            }
            public  void delete(){
                setStroke(Color.BLACK);

                deleteFromGraphManager();
                Group group = (Group) context.getParent();
                if (context.getVij() == null) {
                    return;
                }
                group.getChildren().remove(context.getVij());
                group.getChildren().remove(context.getTxfVij());
                group.getChildren().remove(context.getPointe());
                group.getChildren().remove(context);
            }

            /**
             * @return the vij
             */
            public Label getVij() {
                return vij;
            }

            /**
             * @param vij the vij to set
             */
            public void setVij(Label vij) {
                this.vij = vij;
            }

            /**
             * @return the v_ij
             */
            public double getV_ij() {
                return v_ij;
            }

            /**
             * @param v_ij the v_ij to set
             */
            public void setV_ij(double v_ij) {
                this.v_ij = v_ij;
            }

            /**
             * @return the arcSerializable
             */
            public ArcSerializable getArcSerializable() {
                return arcSerializable;
            }

            /**
             * @param arcSerializable the arcSerializable to set
             */
            public void setArcSerializable(ArcSerializable arcSerializable) {
                this.arcSerializable = arcSerializable;
            }

            /**
             * @return the controller
             */
            public FordFulkersonFXController getController() {
                return controller;
            }

            /**
             * @param controller the controller to set
             */
            public void setController(FordFulkersonFXController controller) {
                this.controller = controller;
            }

               public void deleteFromGraphManager(){
                   ArrayList arcFXList = getController().getGraphManager().getArcFXList();
                   for (int i = 0; i  "+this.getListSommets().get(1).getID();
                   return str;
               }

        }
```

public void lier(DoubleProperty startX,DoubleProperty startY,DoubleProperty endX,DoubleProperty endY); bind coordinate of circle to quadcurve.

    My problem is on private void enableDrag(); method i can't handle arrow(Pointe) to follow quadCurve(ArcFX). This method is the same as in the tutorial and i just modify a few lines.

```
            /*
             * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
             * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
             * and open the template in the editor.
             */
            package edu.emit.project.view.shape;

            import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
            import javafx.scene.shape.QuadCurve;

            /**
             *
             * @author heniroger
             */

            public class Pointe extends Polygon{
                private final Pointe context = this;
                Double[] points = {0.0, 10.0, -10.0, -10.0, 10.0, -10.0};
                private QuadCurve lien;
                private Double radius;

                public Pointe() {
                    this.getPoints().addAll(points);

                }
                public void linkTo(QuadCurve lien,double sommetRadius){
                    this.lien = lien;
                    this.radius = sommetRadius * 1.25;
                    initialize();

                }

                private void initialize() {
                    double angle = Math.atan2(lien.getEndY() - lien.getStartY(), lien.getEndX() - lien.getStartX()) * 180 / 3.14;

                    double height = lien.getEndY() - lien.getStartY();
                    double width = lien.getEndX() - lien.getStartX();
                    double length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(height, 2) + Math.pow(width, 2));

                    double subtractWidth = radius * width / length;
                    double subtractHeight = radius * height / length;

                    setRotate(angle - 90);
                    setTranslateX(lien.getStartX());
                    setTranslateY(lien.getStartY());
                    setTranslateX(lien.getEndX()- subtractWidth);
                    setTranslateY(lien.getEndY() - subtractHeight);

                }

                public void update(){
                    initialize();
                }



            }
```

Comment: please post the relevant part of your code and try to explain in more detail what exactly you want to behave differently.

Comment: I need some help to the mathematics formula in the Pointe::initialize() methode to translate and follow an ArcFX(QuadCurve) coordination .