# JavaFX: Re-sizeable component

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I wish to know if there is a component in JavaFX that can be re-sized by dragging its edges. I am in the process of coding for a resizeable rectangle so any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in component in JavaFX which includes resizing by edge dragging.

[SplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) would be the closest thing but is probably not what you want.

You probably want to have component resizing like the SceneBuilder application where you have manual resizing anchors you can drag to resize the component (like in this SceneBuilder screen shot below):

[image: resizer]

[SceneBuilder source is online](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/tip/apps/scenebuilder/), so you could look through it and determine how they set up their resizing controls for components.

If you continue to write your own implementation to manage manual resizing, perhaps the draggable anchor logic from the answer to [CubicCurve JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056795/cubiccurve-javafx) may be useful.