# Draw Cartesian Plane Graph with canvas in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have this method to draw the Cartesian plane in JavaFX, using canvas

```
    public class Grafics extends StackPane {

       private Canvas canvas;

           public void Grafics(){ 

            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            grid.setPadding(new Insets(5));
            grid.setHgap(10);
            grid.setVgap(10);             

            canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.setHeight(500);
            canvas.setWidth(700);
            GridPane.setHalignment(canvas, HPos.CENTER);
            grid.add(canvas, 0, 2);

            GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            gc.fillRect(1, 1, canvas.getWidth() - 2, canvas.getHeight() - 2);

           drawAxesXY(gc); //call the method drawAxes

           getChildren().addAll(grid);// add an gridpane in stackpane
         }



private void drawAxesXY(GraphicsContext gc1) {

            gc1 = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter();  

            PixelWriter pixelWriter = gc1.getPixelWriter();

            gc1.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            gc1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            gc1.setLineWidth(1.5);
            gc1.strokeText("Y", 350, 30);
            gc1.scale(1, 1);  
            gc1.translate((canvas.getHeight() / 50) - (canvas.getWidth() / 10), canvas.getHeight() / 50);
           gc1.strokeLine(canvas.getWidth() - 300, canvas.getWidth() - 300, canvas.getHeight() - 100, canvas.getHeight() / 30) ;
           pixelWriter.setColor(300, 300, Color.RED); //use here


           gc1.strokeText("X", 620, 220);  
           gc1.translate(canvas.getWidth() - (canvas.getHeight() / 10), -220);
           gc1.rotate(90.0);
           gc1.setFill(Color.BLACK);
           gc1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
           gc1.setLineWidth(1.5);
           gc1.strokeLine(canvas.getWidth() - 250, canvas.getWidth() - 250,
                                    canvas.getHeight() - 50, canvas.getHeight() / 30);

           pixelWriter.setColor(620, 220, Color.RED);//use here

                                }
                            }
```

this is the draw of my codes http://postimg.org/image/uipe1mgyb/

and I want to draw like this examples http://postimg.org/image/98k9mvnb3/

in another post, they recommended me to use a PixelWriter to write pixels in a Canvas.  I tried it, but it doesn't do anything.

I think the method I'm using to draw the Cartesian plane using canvas in JavaFX is not correct, do not have another method to draw Cartesian plane in JavaFX, without using PixelWriter.

How do I draw a Cartesian plane with canvas in JavaFX and show the coordinates of the axes (x, y) axes and (-x,-y), like the example does?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd advise using the [Scene Graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/scene-graph-tutorial/scenegraph.htm) and the built-in [NumberAxis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html) nodes rather than writing your own cartesian axis renderer using a [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html).

[image: sample plot]

The code below is not meant to be a general purpose function plotter, but instead just provides an illustrative sample of how you might create one.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.function.Function;

// Java 8 code
public class CartesianPlot extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        Axes axes = new Axes(
                400, 300,
                -8, 8, 1,
                -6, 6, 1
        );

        Plot plot = new Plot(
                x -> .25 * (x + 4) * (x + 1) * (x - 2),
                -8, 8, 0.1,
                axes
        );

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(
                plot
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(35, 39, 50);");

        stage.setTitle("y = \u00BC(x+4)(x+1)(x-2)");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, Color.rgb(35, 39, 50)));
        stage.show();
    }

    class Axes extends Pane {
        private NumberAxis xAxis;
        private NumberAxis yAxis;

        public Axes(
                int width, int height,
                double xLow, double xHi, double xTickUnit,
                double yLow, double yHi, double yTickUnit
        ) {
            setMinSize(Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE, Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            setPrefSize(width, height);
            setMaxSize(Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE, Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE);

            xAxis = new NumberAxis(xLow, xHi, xTickUnit);
            xAxis.setSide(Side.BOTTOM);
            xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
            xAxis.setPrefWidth(width);
            xAxis.setLayoutY(height / 2);

            yAxis = new NumberAxis(yLow, yHi, yTickUnit);
            yAxis.setSide(Side.LEFT);
            yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
            yAxis.setPrefHeight(height);
            yAxis.layoutXProperty().bind(
                Bindings.subtract(
                    (width / 2) + 1,
                    yAxis.widthProperty()
                )
            );

            getChildren().setAll(xAxis, yAxis);
        }

        public NumberAxis getXAxis() {
            return xAxis;
        }

        public NumberAxis getYAxis() {
            return yAxis;
        }
    }

    class Plot extends Pane {
        public Plot(
                Function<Double, Double> f,
                double xMin, double xMax, double xInc,
                Axes axes
        ) {
            Path path = new Path();
            path.setStroke(Color.ORANGE.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.6));
            path.setStrokeWidth(2);

            path.setClip(
                    new Rectangle(
                            0, 0, 
                            axes.getPrefWidth(), 
                            axes.getPrefHeight()
                    )
            );

            double x = xMin;
            double y = f.apply(x);

            path.getElements().add(
                    new MoveTo(
                            mapX(x, axes), mapY(y, axes)
                    )
            );

            x += xInc;
            while (x < xMax) {
                y = f.apply(x);

                path.getElements().add(
                        new LineTo(
                                mapX(x, axes), mapY(y, axes)
                        )
                );

                x += xInc;
            }

            setMinSize(Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE, Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            setPrefSize(axes.getPrefWidth(), axes.getPrefHeight());
            setMaxSize(Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE, Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE);

            getChildren().setAll(axes, path);
        }

        private double mapX(double x, Axes axes) {
            double tx = axes.getPrefWidth() / 2;
            double sx = axes.getPrefWidth() / 
               (axes.getXAxis().getUpperBound() - 
                axes.getXAxis().getLowerBound());

            return x * sx + tx;
        }

        private double mapY(double y, Axes axes) {
            double ty = axes.getPrefHeight() / 2;
            double sy = axes.getPrefHeight() / 
                (axes.getYAxis().getUpperBound() - 
                 axes.getYAxis().getLowerBound());

            return -y * sy + ty;
        }
    }
}
```

A version of this solution with an additional interactive zoom capability  is provided in an answer to:

- [Making a zoomable coordinate system in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944897/making-a-zoomable-coordinate-system-in-javafx/68945835#68945835)

---

Another user took the code above and created a sample with it that is able to plot arbitrary functions typed in by the user.  The functions are parsed using the [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm):

- [parsing an arithmetic expression using the shunting-yard algorithm and drawing with javafx](http://speedysoft.blogspot.com/2015/08/parsing-arithmetic-expression-using.html)
- [FunctionPlotter source](https://github.com/mooninvader/FunctionPlotter).

Comment: Thanks jewelsea, but to make draw like this http://postimg.org/image/yr16irq2p/, I need to draw the cartesian plane and polygon using Canvas

Comment: I advise using a Scene Graph rather than a canvas for this task, but to each his own.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: How would you use the Scene Graph and built-in NumberAxis nodes as opposed to the code you posted? I make my graph using `NumberAxis` and `LineChart<Number, Number>`.

Comment: I don’t understand your question Fadi.  The code I posted does use the scene graph and the NumberAxis.