# Position JavaFX X and Y Axis In Center

Tags: java, javafx, graph, axis

[image]

This is the graph produced by JavaFX. Does anyone know how to position the x and y axis to be in the middle of the graph, along those gray lines?

For claification, "middle" means something like this, where the axis is in the center:[image]

Comment: What do you mean by in the middle? Your question is unclear, I think it is more related to mathematics than to JavaFX

Comment: @adxl I just edited the question to include a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Does this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008426/9104087 ?

Comment: A bit. This solution requires having to work with other classes. If possible, I'm trying to use `NumberAxis` and `LineChart<Number, Number>`. Thank you, though!

Comment: I'm not familiar with chart stuff, but I think that if you provide some code maybe someone could help you :)

Comment: I think I'm just going to try to contact the person who provided the answer in the link you sent me. Thank you so much!